# SAPUI5 / OpenUI5: Double Conditional binding in XML view

Tags: binding, conditional-statements, sapui5

I would like to use conditional binding in my XML view but have two conditions, such as this:

```
visible="{= ${viewModel>/selectedTabKey} === 'aaa' &amp;&amp; ${viewModel>/editMode} === true}"
```

This is equivalent to the example [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html) (escaped "&&"!).
But when running this, I do get this error:

```
BindingParser-dbg.js:341 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected '}' and instead saw '' in expression binding {= ${viewModel>/editMode} === true at position 34
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: You must be using `{= ${viewModel>/editMode} === true` somewhere else. I don't think the error comes from the code snippet you supplied to us since it doesn't contain any syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only point I see in your sample is that

```
${viewModel>/editMode} === true
```

is redundant and should be simplified to

```
${viewModel>/editMode}
```

BUT your error message seems to point elsewhere since it explicitly shows another code

```
{= ${viewModel>/editMode} === true
```

(which is not in your sample)